# Shutter not including cursor when taking selection screenshot

Tags: cursor, screenshot, shutter

I have shutter with option to include cursor checked:

[image]

However when I take a selection screenshot, the cursor disappears:

[image]

I'm running Shutter `0.93.1`, which is the latest version I could get via ppa: http://shutter-project.org/faq-help/ppa-installation-guide/

However I'm confused, Shutter say they have a 0.94 with many bugfixes: http://shutter-project.org/2017/09/after-a-long-time-a-new-bug-fix-release-0-94/

However if I go to the source repository (http://shutter-project.org/wp-content/uploads/releases/tars/), the latest is `0.93.1`

**Anybody with the same problem and/or who managed to find `0.94`?**

Answer (score 0):

The Shutter 0.94 source is available on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/shutter/+download). Shutter 0.94 is available in the Ubuntu 18.04 repositories. For Ubuntu 17.04 or 16.04 (there are no packages for 17.10), you can get Shutter 0.94 from [an unofficial PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/apps/+packages?field.name_filter=shutter&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=).

Regarding the cursor issue specifically, if Shutter 0.94 doesn't fix this for you, there's a workaround: after taking a screenshot, click "Edit" in the toolbar (this should open the Shutter Drawing Tool), then in the Drawing Tool, click "Insert image" at the bottom, and select the cursor you want - you can place it anywhere in your screenshot, change its size, etc.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try. Workaround is not adequate: the whole point of using a screenshot tool like Shutter is to gain in productivity, having to edit images manually to insert cursors it's really self-defeating